# Nested Wrapper data not being return in lightning component callback

Tags: lightning-aura-components, json, wrapper-class

I currently have this very nested wrapper class,

```
    public sharing class ResultWrapper {

    //This wrapper is contain more wrappers that goes as far as 5 level deep. 
    @AuraEnabled public VerifyResWrapper.ResponseWrapper resResponse { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled public String AccountId { get; set; }
    }
```

so, in the service console I am able to see that the data was properly set to the wrapper class

```
12:23:44:008 USER_DEBUG [22]|DEBUG|result==>ResultWrapper:[resResponse=ResponseWrapper:[Number='123, Detail=OutcomeWrapper:[NextSteps=ContentWrapper:[......
```

In my lightning controller class it looks something like this...

```
    @AuraEnabled
public static ResultWrapper getQuestion{
    ResultWrapper resultObject= new ResultWrapper();

    //sample json string.
    string json_string ='...';

    resultObject.AccountId = '1234567';
    resultObject.AuthResponse = (VerifyResWrapper.ResponseWrapper)System.JSON.deserialize(json_string, VerifyResWrapper.ResponseWrapper.class);

    system.debug('Response==>' + result);

    return resultObject; 
}
```

So when I debug the response.getReturnValue().

```
console.log('response' + JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
```

This is the result it return the Account Id, but showing nothing for the nested wrapper class:

```
response:{"resResponse":{},"AccountId":"1234567"}
```

Is there something I a missing here, or had run into a limitation?

Comment: I think you need to make each variable of the wrapper class as aura enabled. just the wrapper class definition wont do

Comment: My first thought is that you are using 2 different class attribute names: `ResultWrapper.resResponse` and `ResultWrapper.AuthResponse`. Can you include enough code to explain that and also include the ResponseWrapper class in your question? Also, what is in the debug log for the "Response==>" system.debug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to annotate all members of the inner wrapper class as `@AuraEnabled` whichever wrappers variables you need on UI